# How to use Hsytrix to be the gateway for multiple webapps

Tags: hystrix

We have many web apps deployed in tomcat container. All these applications, make REST API calls to a couple of external services. What we want is all these rest API calls (across these web apps) to be going via single Hystrix gateway so we can build resiliency into the system. Any idea how to do this? If these independent web apps package hystrix in their own war then there will be multiple hystrix instances created? How to have a single instance of Hystrix per JVM which should deal with multiple web apps ?

Thanks,
Sidd

Comment: what do you mean single instance of hystrix? hystrix is a library and you can create as many commands as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a gateway that will serve as a reverse proxy to dispatch incoming requests to the different services. This gateway can implement hystrix commands in order make the calls to the different external services.

Look at [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) made by Netflix it's the most popular choice in terms of gateways. Hystrix is already in place and wraps the different external calls. You can also use spring cloud Netflix which includes an embedded Zuul proxy, here's an example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/